# Transforming a list of lists to a table

Tags: r

I have a list of lists as follows assigned to an object SR2:

```
List of 16
num [1:5] 143 68 16 10 1
num [1:5] 60.1 28.6 6.7 4.2 0.4
num [1:5] 44 6 0 0 2
num [1:5] 84.6 11.5 0 0 3.8
num [1:5] 70 7 0 0 0
num [1:5] 90.9 9.1 0 0 0
num [1:5] 15 1 1 0 1
num [1:5] 83.3 5.6 5.6 0 5.6
num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
num [1:5] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
num [1:5] 1 1 0 0 0
num [1:5] 50 50 0 0 0
num [1:5] 6 0 0 0 0
num [1:5] 100 0 0 0 0
num [1:5] 1 1 0 0 0
num [1:5] 50 50 0 0 0
attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 8
attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
chr [1:2] "n" "%"
chr [1:8] "Researcher, scientist or scholar" "Research administrator" "Librarian" "Publisher" ...
```

I'm trying to convert this to a table for easy reading.

The following returns the expected layout, but renames all the columns.

```
SR3 <- lapply(SR2, as.data.frame, colnames = names(SR[[2]]))
SR4 <- bind_cols(SR3)
```

Output:

```
SR4
X[[i]]...1 X[[i]]...2 X[[i]]...3 X[[i]]...4 X[[i]]...5 X[[i]]...6 X[[i]]...7 X[[i]]...8 
1        143       60.1         44       84.6         70       90.9         15       83.3          
2         68       28.6          6       11.5          7        9.1          1        5.6          
3         16        6.7          0        0.0          0        0.0          1        5.6          
4         10        4.2          0        0.0          0        0.0          0        0.0          
5          1        0.4          2        3.8          0        0.0          1        5.6          
etc...
```

I would like the output column titles to be the intersection of the original list (SR2) dimension names, i.e. column one would indicate that it pertains to Researchers & it is the n-value.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please include output of `dput(SR2)` in your question? It would make it reproducible for others.

Comment: does `list2DF(SR2)` help?

Comment: Your list already has a `dim` attribute. If using R >4.3.0 make use of the function `array2DF`

Comment: Thank you very much for you time responding to my question. @Onyambu your solution works!